# How should I handle exceptions for invalid generic type arguments?

Tags: c#, exception

How should I handle exceptions for invalid generic type arguments?
Should I make my own class? InvalidOperationException or ArgumentException? I'm not too sure on how to 'handle' this...

Comment: Just don't.  Write generic code that *never* depends on the type arguments.  If you have to veto a particular type then you're not writing generic code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would let the compiler do it for me with [contraints on the type parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx).

Comment: I'd add that this sounds like something you should have validated by the compiler and not at run-time (exceptions).